# Why does my self-built PyGObject segfault on importing Gtk or Gdk?

Tags: python, gtk

**Edit**: I have tried importing almost every library represented in `/usr/lib/girepository-1.0` through `gi.repository` and they all work except Gtk and Gdk. I have updated the title to reflect this.

---

I need a self-built PyGObject library to go with my self-built Python 3.3.3. I installed all the dependencies for PyGObject using `sudo apt-get build-dep python3-gi`. I found that the working system PyGObject version was 3.2.2, so I checked out version 3.2.2 of the source from the Git repo. I ran:

```
autoreconf --force --install
./configure --prefix=/home/tomas/.pyenv/versions/3.3.3
make
make install
```

Everything compiled and installed beautifully. I opened a fresh CMD and set the working directory to `~`, then:

```
~$ python
Python 3.3.3 (default, Dec 21 2013, 23:12:28) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from gi.repository import Gtk
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
~$
```

I have set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/home/tomas/.pyenv/versions/3.3.3/lib` and checked that the correct library is being loaded:

```
~$ ldd .pyenv/versions/3.3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/gi/_gi.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffcdf51000)
    libgirepository-1.0.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgirepository-1.0.so.1 (0x00007f45d8304000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f45d80b5000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f45d7dbf000)
    libpyglib-gi-2.0-python.so.0 => /home/tomas/.pyenv/versions/3.3.3/lib/libpyglib-gi-2.0-python.so.0 (0x00007f45d7bba000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f45d799d000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f45d75dc000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f45d72e0000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f45d70dc000)
    libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f45d6d8c000)
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f45d6b84000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f45d6947000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f45d673e000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f45d877b000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f45d653a000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f45d6323000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f45d6103000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f45d5ee7000)
```

I also imported the module with `python -vv`: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/xhUVvTzj)

The last few lines reveals that the core dump happens right after importing `gi.repository.Atk`:

```
# trying /home/tomas/.pyenv/versions/3.3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/gi/repository/Atk.cpython-33m.so
# trying /home/tomas/.pyenv/versions/3.3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/gi/repository/Atk.abi3.so
# trying /home/tomas/.pyenv/versions/3.3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/gi/repository/Atk.so
# trying /home/tomas/.pyenv/versions/3.3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/gi/repository/Atk.py
# trying /home/tomas/.pyenv/versions/3.3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/gi/repository/Atk.pyc
# trying /home/tomas/.pyenv/versions/3.3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/gi/overrides/Atk.cpython-33m.so
# trying /home/tomas/.pyenv/versions/3.3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/gi/overrides/Atk.abi3.so
# trying /home/tomas/.pyenv/versions/3.3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/gi/overrides/Atk.so
# trying /home/tomas/.pyenv/versions/3.3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/gi/overrides/Atk.py
# trying /home/tomas/.pyenv/versions/3.3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/gi/overrides/Atk.pyc
import 'gi.repository.Atk' # 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Importing just `gi.repository.Atk` doesn't segfault.

I have also tried removing the system version of the library (`sudo dpkg -P python3-gi`) in case it was interfering in some way.

---

I don't know what else to do. Does anybody know or have any idea what the problem might be? Please leave a comment if you have an idea of something I could try or if I can provide more information.

Comment: Can you get a stacktrace when it happens?

Comment: @drahnr: I can print [a stack trace from the core](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=19rETAkn), but it's not very helpful without a symbol table.

Comment: Can you recompile python with debug symbols? Note, I am not sure this helps but I think it's a starting point. You should also post to the gtk-devel mailinglist - maybe some of the core devs/introspect maintainers have a clue.

Comment: @drahnr: I've now compiled both Python and PyGObject with debug symbols. The stack trace still makes little sense to me, but at least it's much larger now! http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=W4vhd3rj

Comment: Not much to see, except for being related to some ceval foo, which was kinda expected...

Comment: @drahnr: Any other info I can provide? Any clue what could be wrong?

Comment: Not sure if it works, but try to get a backtrace when running gdb --args python yourfunfile.py and get a backtrace - usually that leaves more information than strace in regard to what is going wrong.

Comment: @drahnr: Like this? http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=4QvA23VM

Comment: Yes indeed like that... I'll have a look later on, but I never dug into the python interpreter code nor the ctypes code.

Answer (score 7):

PyGObject has strong prerequisites about Glib and Python.

For what it worth, I batch-build various combination sets in order to find the working ones.

Please note that, as Simon Feltman explained in a comment below, pycairo is not a strict dependency and might be disabled using the `--enable-cairo=no` configure option. It appears only here as I've performed those tests using the *default* build options.

Here are the results on my Debian Wheezy/Wheezy-backports system (GLib 2.33):

```
python      pygobject   pycairo     compile           ... import Gtk    

3.1         3.0         1.0         NO (pycairo)                        
3.1         3.0         1.10        YES               OK                
3.1         3.0         1.2         NO (pycairo)                        
3.1         3.0         1.4         NO (pycairo)                        
3.1         3.0         1.6         NO (pycairo)                        
3.1         3.0         1.8         NO (pycairo)                        
3.1         3.2         1.0         NO (pycairo)                        
3.1         3.2         1.10        YES               OK                
3.1         3.2         1.2         NO (pycairo)                        
3.1         3.2         1.4         NO (pycairo)                        
3.1         3.2         1.6         NO (pycairo)                        
3.1         3.2         1.8         NO (pycairo)                        
3.1         3.4         1.0         NO (pycairo)                        
3.1         3.4         1.10        NO (pygobject)                      
3.1         3.4         1.2         NO (pycairo)                        
3.1         3.4         1.4         NO (pycairo)                        
3.1         3.4         1.6         NO (pycairo)                        
3.1         3.4         1.8         NO (pycairo)                        
3.1         3.6         1.0         NO (pycairo)                        
3.1         3.6         1.10        NO (pycairo)                        
3.1         3.6         1.2         NO (pycairo)                        
3.1         3.6         1.4         NO (pycairo)                        
3.1         3.6         1.6         NO (pycairo)                        
3.1         3.6         1.8         NO (pycairo)                        
3.1         3.8         1.0         NO (pycairo)                        
3.1         3.8         1.10        NO (pygobject)                      
3.1         3.8         1.2         NO (pycairo)                        
3.1         3.8         1.4         NO (pycairo)                        
3.1         3.8         1.6         NO (pycairo)                        
3.1         3.8         1.8         NO (pycairo)                        
3.2         3.0         1.0         NO (pycairo)                        
3.2         3.0         1.10        YES               OK                
3.2         3.0         1.2         NO (pycairo)                        
3.2         3.0         1.4         NO (pycairo)                        
3.2         3.0         1.6         NO (pycairo)                        
3.2         3.0         1.8         NO (pycairo)                        
3.2         3.2         1.0         NO (pycairo)                        
3.2         3.2         1.10        YES               OK                
3.2         3.2         1.2         NO (pycairo)                        
3.2         3.2         1.4         NO (pycairo)                        
3.2         3.2         1.6         NO (pycairo)                        
3.2         3.2         1.8         NO (pycairo)                        
3.2         3.4         1.0         NO (pycairo)                        
3.2         3.4         1.10        NO (pygobject)                      
3.2         3.4         1.2         NO (pycairo)                        
3.2         3.4         1.4         NO (pycairo)                        
3.2         3.4         1.6         NO (pycairo)                        
3.2         3.4         1.8         NO (pycairo)                        
3.2         3.6         1.0         NO (pycairo)                        
3.2         3.6         1.10        NO (pycairo)                        
3.2         3.6         1.2         NO (pycairo)                        
3.2         3.6         1.4         NO (pycairo)                        
3.2         3.6         1.6         NO (pycairo)                        
3.2         3.6         1.8         NO (pycairo)                        
3.2         3.8         1.0         NO (pycairo)                        
3.2         3.8         1.10        NO (pygobject)                      
3.2         3.8         1.2         NO (pycairo)                        
3.2         3.8         1.4         NO (pycairo)                        
3.2         3.8         1.6         NO (pycairo)                        
3.2         3.8         1.8         NO (pycairo)                        
3.3         3.0         1.0         NO (pycairo)                        
3.3         3.0         1.10        YES               SEGMENTATION FAULT
3.3         3.0         1.2         NO (pycairo)                        
3.3         3.0         1.4         NO (pycairo)                        
3.3         3.0         1.6         NO (pycairo)                        
3.3         3.0         1.8         NO (pycairo)                        
3.3         3.2         1.0         NO (pycairo)                        
3.3         3.2         1.10        YES               SEGMENTATION FAULT
3.3         3.2         1.2         NO (pycairo)                        
3.3         3.2         1.4         NO (pycairo)                        
3.3         3.2         1.6         NO (pycairo)                        
3.3         3.2         1.8         NO (pycairo)                        
3.3         3.4         1.0         NO (pycairo)                        
3.3         3.4         1.10        NO (pygobject)                      
3.3         3.4         1.2         NO (pycairo)                        
3.3         3.4         1.4         NO (pycairo)                        
3.3         3.4         1.6         NO (pycairo)                        
3.3         3.4         1.8         NO (pycairo)                        
3.3         3.6         1.0         NO (pycairo)                        
3.3         3.6         1.10        NO (pycairo)                        
3.3         3.6         1.2         NO (pycairo)                        
3.3         3.6         1.4         NO (pycairo)                        
3.3         3.6         1.6         NO (pycairo)                        
3.3         3.6         1.8         NO (pycairo)                        
3.3         3.8         1.0         NO (pycairo)                        
3.3         3.8         1.10        NO (pygobject)                      
3.3         3.8         1.2         NO (pycairo)                        
3.3         3.8         1.4         NO (pycairo)                        
3.3         3.8         1.6         NO (pycairo)                        
3.3         3.8         1.8         NO (pycairo)
```

Many combinations just won't build because they require a more recent version of GLib than available on my system. In some cases, the `setup.py` script require python-2, hence the installation process failed on a python-3 only environment. I didn't take take time to understand **why** some combinations result in a *segmentation fault* at run-time.

As you can see, your best bet (at least *today* on Debian) is to build pycairo-1.10 + pygobject-3.2 + python 3.2. anything more up to date will require at least a more recent version of GLib...

Comment: Note that pycairo is not a strict dependency. It is needed for GUI code that needs to do custom widget drawing with cairo. This can be removed with the configure flag "--enable-cairo=no" and in fact most distros break this out into a separate package. In terms of having a Python devel dependency, it is a Python C extension after all. As far as thinking PyGObject is "punctilious", that is actually useful feedback for me as a maintainer!

Comment: Thank you Simon for your comment ... and your time working as a maintainer on PyGObject ;) Maybe the word "punctilious" is more negative in English as I thought? Anyway, don't take my words wrong: I was mostly disappointed of not being able to use a more recent version than 3.2 on my Debian box. All the above results are using the default build options. To be honest, as I struggled on the same issue (`Segmentation fault`) as the OP, I've performed only that bunch of "quick and dirty" builds as a test ... without taking time to explore the various configure options! Shame on me...

Comment: @SimonFeltman I rephrased the first few paragraphs of the answer to take your comment into account. Don't hesitate to let me know if you think this answer has still some issues.

Comment: I am awestruck at the amount of work represented by this answer, if disappointed to discover my own efforts to use python3.3 and pygobject in Debian Wheezy are in vain.